# UI.calendar/fullCalendar: Week and Days hours Format

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

first of all, im aware to all full calendar format questions here, read them all, but still no success.

im trying to format week and day hours in fullCalendar, but nothing works.

```
        $scope.initCalendar = function() {
        /* config object */
        $scope.uiConfig = {
            calendar: {
                height: '450',
                editable: false,
                header: {
                    left: 'agendaWeek',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: false
                },
                slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
                axisFormat: 'h:mm a',
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm a',
                minTime: '00:00',
                maxTime: '23:00',
                eventSources: [$scope.events],
                titleFormat: 'MMM',
                columnFormat: 'MMM',
                eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                    $scope.title = (event.title);
                    $scope.note = (event.note);
                    $scope.eventDate = (event.date);
                    $scope.userInfo = (event.displayname);
                    $scope.url_code = (event.url_code);

                    $('#event-modal').modal({
                        show: true
                    });

                    var index = $scope.events.indexOf(event);
                    $scope.remove = function(index){
                        $calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (ev) {
                            return (ev._id == event._id);
                        });
                    };

                    $scope.isDone = function () {
                        event.backgroundColor = 'green';
                        $calendar.fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
                    };


                    $calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

this is how it look like:

```
2017-07-16T06:00:00:2017-07-16T06:00:002017-07-16T06:00:00
```

tried, slot, axis, timeformat, still no success.
trying to make it from 6am to 11pm
thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where you want date format? Any code fiddle will help to understand issue

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean either? Which thing on the calendar are you trying to format, and what output do you want? You say "this is how it look like"...then give an abstract string...where is that string in the context of your calendar setup?

Comment: sorry, agenda week hours, and agenda day. trying to make it 6am....11pm

Comment: image: [link](http://imgur.com/LUDfMcy)

Comment: this is what im trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/2ELLR/255/

Comment: As far as I can see the times are already formatted in the "6am" style, so that's not a problem. Do you mean you want the day to start at 6am and end at 11pm? minTime and maxTime do this -
 see here: http://jsfiddle.net/2ELLR/256/

Comment: yes, but time format dosent work for me, dont know why, uploaded an image

Comment: as per my JSfiddle you don't even need to set the time format. The format you're asking for is already the default. Unless I have misunderstood what you want?

Comment: yep, thats what i cant understand, maybe becouse its ui calendar directive, i gess i need to start all over